# AlarmManager on Reboot

Tags: android, startup, alarmmanager

I'm trying to create an alarm that resets itself when the device restarts. Is this the correct way to do it (assuming the Android manifest is correct)? The code seems to be crashing my app.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     Context cxt;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     cxt = context;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1234, 
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.neelsomani.meds.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2265)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at com.neelsomani.meds.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:40)
01-28 00:35:00.263: E/AndroidRuntime(31269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2258)
```

Comment: Posted, not sure whether I formatted it properly.

Comment: what's on line 40 in source code?

Comment: Line 40 is `if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems good, can you give us more detail from the crash please?

Have you declared this broadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
    <receiver android:name="MyAlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have it nested under the `<application>` tag. Added the logcat if that helps.

Comment: Is this java code in its own file ? or in an other activity file ?

Comment: Yes, it's in its own file.

Comment: And eclispe don't show an error on `cxt.` ? because there isn't declaration in this code

Comment: I forgot to include that I have a local variable Context cxt that's set to the context passed to the BroadcastReceiver. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: If you set it in the receive method with `ctx = context;` it wouldn't

Comment: What's is the 40th line  of AlarmReceiver.java ?

Comment: Would the code still work if I take out the `if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){` line? As in, would it restart the alarm on boot?

Comment: The 40th line is `if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){`

Comment: Normally you don't need this line, the test is done "by the manifest"

Comment: So could I just restart the PendingIntent every time the BroadcastReceiver is called?

Comment: If you remove your if test, this pending intent will be throw each time the BroadcastReceiver is called (here, each time the boot is completed)

Comment: But it's not recursive, right? This won't mean that the PendingIntent will be thrown over and over again?

Comment: No your broadcast receiver received only broadcast intent with boot_completed (as indicate in the manifest) not the broadcast from your pending intent.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) h);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) m);
```

plz use this PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Answer (score 0):

Your context is wrong. Pass correct context,

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) cxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Change to

> AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)
>   context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);